# Function plot through plotter plotting point not in domain/range

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

> Given $f(x)=(x^{2}-1)/(x+1)$ where domain of $f(x)= \mathbb{R} - \{-1\}$ and range of $f(x) = \mathbb{R} - \{-2\}$.

When the graph is plotted on Wolfram Alpha, the graph is a straight line where $\hspace{0.1mm} x \hspace{1mm} \epsilon \hspace{1mm} [-1.7,1.1] $.

Please find attached the plot for the same.

[image]

Had a question regarding the attached plot. why it calculates the limit of the function when x tends to -1 while plotting?

Comment: Because it can't plot the point at $x=-1$. Or did you mean something else with your question?

Comment: @Andrei yes but in the graph it is not showing the irregularity like highlighting on the coordinate as it is not belonging to the domain/range of the function

Comment: For $x\ne -1$ you have $f(x)=x-1$. How else would you plot this function?

Comment: Yes but at  x = -1 it is giving f(x) as -2 in the plot

Comment: How do you know that $x=-1$ is shown in the plot?Maybe you only have points at $-1.000001$ and $-0.999998$

Comment: @Andrei ok got it thanks